# Proposition about absolutely convergence of sequences relating to Riemann's zeta function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions, absolute-convergence

$\{ a_n \} ,\{b_n\}$ : bounded sequences

I have to prove this proposition;

For $s\in \mathbb{C} \,\, (\text{Re}(s)>1),$

$
\left( \sum_{k=1}^　{\infty} \dfrac{a_k}{k^s} \right)
\left(\sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{b_l}{l^s}\right)
\text{ and } \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{c_m}{m^s}
\quad (c_m:=\sum_{k,l\geqq 1, kl=m} a_k b_l)$
converge absolutely. Furthermore,
$\left( \sum_{k=1}^　{\infty} \dfrac{a_k}{k^s} \right)
\left(\sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{b_l}{l^s}\right)
=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{c_m}{m^s}
$

My attempt is as following.

Because $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are bounded, there exist $K, M>0$ such that $|a_n|\leqq K, |b_n|\leqq M$ for all $n$.

Therefore,

$ \sum_{k=1}^　 {\infty} \Bigg|\dfrac{a_k}{k^s}\Bigg| \leqq K\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k^s}, \,\, \sum_{l=1}^　 {\infty} \Bigg|\dfrac{b_l}{l^s}\Bigg| \leqq M\sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{l^s}$. And because Re$(s)>1$, both convergent absolutely.
Thus, $
\left( \sum_{k=1}^　{\infty} \dfrac{a_k}{k^s} \right)
\left(\sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{b_l}{l^s}\right)$ convergent absolutely.

But I cannot prove
$
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{c_m}{m^s}
$ convergents absolutely and
$\left( \sum_{k=1}^　{\infty} \dfrac{a_k}{k^s} \right)
\left(\sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{b_l}{l^s}\right)
=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{c_m}{m^s}.$

For the convergence of $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{c_m}{m^s}$,
I tried
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \Bigg| \dfrac{c_m}{m^s} \Bigg|
&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \Bigg(
\dfrac{1}{m^s} \Bigg|\sum_{k,l\geqq 1, kl=m} a_k b_l \Bigg|
\Bigg)\\
&\leqq \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \Bigg(
\dfrac{1}{m^s} \sum_{k,l\geqq 1, kl=m}\Bigg| a_k b_l \Bigg|\Bigg)
\\
&\leqq \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \Bigg(
\dfrac{1}{m^s} \sum_{k,l\geqq 1, kl=m}KM \Bigg).
\\
\end{align}
But I cannot proceed.
And I have no idea to prove $\left( \sum_{k=1}^　{\infty} \dfrac{a_k}{k^s} \right)
\left(\sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{b_l}{l^s}\right)
=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{c_m}{m^s}$.

I would like you to give me some ideas.

Comment: note that $c_m:=\sum_{k,l\geq 1, kl=m} a_k b_l$ implies $|c_m| \le d(m)KM$ where $d(m)$ is the number of divisors of $m$; since $d(m)/m^{\epsilon} \to 0, m \to \infty$ for any $\epsilon >0$ it immediately follows that $\sum c_mm^{-s}$ converges absolutely for $\Re s >1$; from here showing the equality $AB=C$ follows immediately